# Call method in servlet

Tags: java

I want to call a method of nother class in the servlet but I have error ... this is the code

```html
package com.jnext.webapp;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class x {

 public static void jaw(String image) {
 

byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(image);
  
  
  FileOutputStream imageOutFile;
  try {
   imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("D://winner.jpg");
  
  try {
   imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);
  
  
  imageOutFile.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}


public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) { 
 return Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString.getBytes());
 
}
}
```

and this is the servlet

```js
package com.jnext.webapp;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.jnext.webapp.xxxxxx;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


public class test extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
  public test() {
        super();
        
    }
     
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 

 }

 
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 
  x.jaw(name);
  
  
}
}
```

I want to call a method of nother class in the servlet but I have error ... this is the code

Comment: Simple Create the instance for Class and Call method name

Answer (score 1):

You do not post the error.
first post the error.
and i think you get the error because of the import statement.
**import com.jnext.webapp.xxxxxx;** 
change the code like this
**import com.jnext.webapp.x;**

Answer (score 0):

You can't call static methods in a class using non-static methods.
You can change the jaw function as non-static in class X and then call the jaw function using an object from the servlet.